# default parameters in c++

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
int foo(int x , int z = 0);
int foo(int x, int y , int z = 0);
```

If I call this function like so:

```
foo( 1 , 2);
```

How does the compiler know which one to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't and hence this example will not compile cleanly, it will give you an compilation error.
It will give you an ambiguous function call error.

**[Online Sample:](http://ideone.com/2CSQM)**

```
int foo(int x , int z = 0){return 0;} 
int foo(int x, int y , int z = 0){return 10;}

int main()
{
    foo( 1 , 2); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:6: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(int, int)’ is ambiguous
>   prog.cpp:1: note: candidates are: int foo(int, int)
>   prog.cpp:2: note:                 int foo(int, int, int)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't, that's why you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

That is a nice question. But it will not compile because of ambigious call to `foo()`. You can remove this ambiguity by using different datatypes in function signature.

For more detail about **default parameter** and **function overloading** see http://www.smart2help.com/e-books/ticpp-2nd-ed-vol-one/Chapter07.html

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will report Ambiguous function overload. As you cannot figure out which function will b called so does the compiler